# JQuery get content of span

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the content of a span when a button is clicked.  This is the html:

```
<div class="multiple-result">
<button class="select-location" id="168">Select</button>
<span>Athens, Greece</span>
</div>

<div class="multiple-result">
<button class="select-location" id="102">Select</button>
<span>Athens, Georgia, USA</span>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get it so that when the button is clicked it will get the value of the span.  This is what I'm using:

```
$('button.select-location').live('click', function(event){

  // set the span value
  var span_val = $(this).parent("span").html();

  alert('selecting...' + span_val);

});
```

But the alert is always showing: selecting... null

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You want to get the parent first, then find the span:

```
var span_val = $(this).parent().find("> span").html();
```

---

**Edit:** [Ever go back and look at code you wrote 2 years ago](http://frontenddevreactions.tumblr.com/post/50427701984/when-i-look-at-code-i-wrote-years-ago) and groan, "Why did I do *that*?".  The above code is awkward.  Instead of `.find("> span")`, I should have used `.children("span")`.

```
var span_val = $(this).parent().children("span").html();
```

But, what is a child of your parent? A sibling! So, instead of `.parent().children("span")`, I should have used `.siblings("span")`.

```
var span_val = $(this).siblings("span").html();
```

But, looking at the HTML, we don't even need to dig through the siblings, we know it's the next sibling:

```
var span_val = $(this).next("span").html();
```

or just:

```
var span_val = $(this).next().html();
```

By this point, we're barely using jQuery at all.  We *could* just say:

```
var span_val = this.nextSibling.innerHTML;
```

But, maybe now I've swung the pendulum too far the other way?

Comment: I love this answer. This is pretty much how my internal monologue sounds every day.  This deserves more than 6 upvotes!

Comment: voted up for `Ever go back and look at code you wrote 2 years ago and groan, "Why did I do that?"`

Comment: And I just logged in ~6 years later (after finding this answer while anonymous) just to upvote the conversation.  So instructive.

Answer (score 1):

It's not button's parent. `div` is `button`'s parent and `span` is children of the `div`. Try

```
var span_val = $(this).parent().children("span").html();
```

instead.

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G5Azg/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$('button.select-location').live('click', function(event){

  var span_val = $(this).next("span").html();

  alert('selecting...' + span_val);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The span isn't a parent of the '.select-location' button, but the div is (which the span is in). Using your markup, try something like this:

```
var spanVal = $(this).parent('.multiple-result').find('span').html();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Jsfiddler demo using [jQuery next](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

http://jsfiddle.net/vVK54/1/

```
$('button.select-location').live('click', function(event){      
  // set the span value
  var span_val = $(this).next().html();
  alert('selecting...' + span_val);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many spans you have but if the span will always come directly after the button then the `.next('span')` will work. If you plan on placing the button anywhere else within the same parent div then you will need to navigate the dom to find it.

```
$('selector').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('span');
)};
```

Also it may be best to add a targetable class or attribute to the span to target it better incase you do plan on a more complex dom or multiple spans.

```
<span class='clicktarget'>Text Here</span>

$('button.select-location').click(function() {
    var span_val = $(this).parent('div').find('span.clicktarget').html();
});
```

Hope this helps