# getting content of a span in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a structure as follows and I want to get content of spans using jquery. How can I do it? Thanks.

```
<div id="question">
    <span id="question_zone_0">
        <span class="myclass">
            <span id="myword0">myword0</span>
        </span>
        <span class="myclass">
            <span id="myword1">myword1</span>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960048/jquery-get-content-of-span

Comment: Try this: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
 var span0 = $('#myword0').text();
 var span1 = $('#myword1').text();
```

or iterate with each

```
 $('#question span').each(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
 })
```